# Get the property for each jsonschema errror

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, jsonschema

I am trying to determine which property caused the error. It seems for each type of error the way to get the property is different.

```
from jsonschema import Draft4Validator

request_json = {
  'num_pages': 'invalid',
  'duration': 'invalid',
  'dne': 'invalid'
}

schema = {
  "patch": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {"type": "string"},
      "location": {},
      "description": {},
      "objectives": {},
      "num_pages": {"type": "integer"},
      "duration": {"type": "integer"}
    },
    "required": ["name"],
    "additionalProperties": False
  }
}

v = Draft4Validator(schema['patch'])
errors = []

for error in v.iter_errors(request_json):
    print error.__dict__
```

From this example I would like to construct output with the field and error.

```
{
  num_pages: 'invalid is not an integer',
  duration: 'invalid is not an integer',
  'dne': 'unexpected additional property',
  'name': 'property is required'
}
```

Currently I have the following

```
    if error.relative_schema_path[0] == 'required':
        errors.append({error.message.split(' ')[0]: 'Required property'})
    elif error.relative_path:
        # field: error_message
        errors.append({error.relative_path[0]: error.message})
    # Additional Field was found
    else:
        errors.append({error.instance.keys()[0]: error.message})
```

If there are multiple errors then error.instance.keys()[0] is not guaranteed to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended approach to traverse and process errors](http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/errors/) is to use an ErrorTree object.

```
tree = ErrorTree(v.iter_errors(instance))
```

From here you can get global errors to the instance:

```
tree.errors
```

Errors for first item in an array:

```
if 1 in tree:
    tree[1].errors
```

Comment: You're right that ErrorTree is the recommended approach but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BARJ, I think the problem is that the question is a bit ambiguous. As I understand it, it has problems to access every error in the validation, so he can build a message with them. I have provided such a means. What do you think is the question?

Comment: Ah right. The question is a bit ambiguous. I think what he meant is that given a validation error, what property caused that error. So for example, if you have a type error, you can use the `schema_path` to find the corresponding property. But if you have a required validation error, it is not as straight forward to trace back what property caused the error. The question is formulated in his first sentence.

Comment: That's what ErrorTree is for. Each error in tree explains which part of your graph made the mistake. There are some examples in the provided link.