# Getting invalid key values from jsonschema using python

Tags: python, jsonschema

Is there an easy way to get set of all keys that failed validation of the jsonschema?

I'm using the Draft4Validator from the jsonschema package and I'm validating a json file against some config and using the `iter_errors` method to iterate through all of the errors. It shows me all of the errors but it would be nice if there was a way to get all of the keys that failed the validation - is this possible?

I've tried going through all of the errors and trying to dig the keys out of the output from the validator but it's getting long and tedious.

EDIT: I am trying to use ErrorTree as per this question: [Get the property for each jsonschema errror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429462/get-the-property-for-each-jsonschema-errror)

```
def get_errors_in_tree(error_tree):
    errors = []
    if error_tree.total_errors <= 1:
        return map(lambda ve: list(ve.instance.keys()),  error_tree.errors.values())
    for error in error_tree:
        errors.extend(get_errors_in_tree(error_tree[error]))
    return errors
```

But it's still not giving me ALL of the invalid keys only some of them.

Here is my schema:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Git Hooks Config",
"description": "Git Hooks Config",
"type" : "object",
"properties" : {
    "git_hooks_config" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
            "prepare_commit_msg": {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "template" : { "type" : "string" }
                },
                "additionalProperties" : false
            },
            "commit_msg": {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "regex" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "regex_flags" : {
                        "type" : "array",
                        "items" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "enum": [ "T", "TEMPLATE", "I", "IGNORECASE",
                                    "L", "LOCALE", "M", "MULTILINE",
                                    "S", "DOTALL", "U", "UNICODE", "X",
                                    "VERBOSE", "DEBUG", "A", "ASCII" ]
                        }
                    },
                    "error_message" : { "type" : "string" }
                },
                "additionalProperties" : false
            },
            "pre_push": {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "validate_branch_name" : { "type" : "boolean" },
                    "branch_name_regex" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "branch_name_regex_flags" : {
                        "type" : "array",
                        "items" : {
                            "type" : "string",
                            "enum": [ "T", "TEMPLATE", "I", "IGNORECASE",
                                    "L", "LOCALE", "M", "MULTILINE",
                                    "S", "DOTALL", "U", "UNICODE", "X",
                                    "VERBOSE", "DEBUG", "A", "ASCII" ]
                        }
                    },
                    "branch_name_error_message" : { "type" : "string" }
                },
                "additionalProperties" : false
            },
            "external_git_hooks": {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "prepare_commit_msg" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "relative_path_to_script" : { "type" : "string" },
                            "when_to_execute" : {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "enum" : [ "before", "after" ]
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties" : false
                    },
                    "commit_msg" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "relative_path_to_script" : { "type" : "string" },
                            "when_to_execute" : {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "enum" : [ "before", "after" ]
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties" : false
                    },
                    "pre_commit" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "relative_path_to_script" : { "type" : "string" },
                            "when_to_execute" : {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "enum" : [ "before", "after" ]
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties" : false
                    },
                    "pre_push" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "properties" : {
                            "relative_path_to_script" : { "type" : "string" },
                            "when_to_execute" : {
                                "type" : "string",
                                "enum" : [ "before", "after" ]
                            }
                        },
                        "additionalProperties" : false
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties" : false
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties" : false
    },
    "repository_properties": {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
            "unvalidated_patterns" : {
                "type" : "array",
                "items" : { "type" : "array" }
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties" : false
    }
},
"additionalProperties" : false
}
```

And here is my config

```
{
"git_hooks_config" : {
    "prepare_commit_msg" : {
        "templadste" : "\nIssue: <JIRA_TICKET_NUMBER>"
    },
    "commit_msg" : {
        "regsex" : ".*",
        "regeax_flags" : [ "DOTALL" ],
        "errdor_message" : "The commit message does not match the supplied regex: '%s'"
    },
    "pre_push" : {
        "validate_branch_name" : true,
        "branch_name_regex" : "^(master|(feature|bugfix|release)/[\\w-]{3,80})$",
        "branch_name_regex_flags" : [ ],
        "branchd_name_error_message" : "The branch name: '%s' does not match the supplied regex: '%s'"
    },
    "external_git_hooks" : {
        "prepare_commit_msg" : {
            "when_to_execute" : "after"
        },
        "commit_msg" : {
            "when_to_execute" : "after"
        },
        "pre_commit" : {
            "when_to_execute" : "after"
        },
        "pre_push" : {
            "when_taso_execute" : "after"
        }
    }
},
"repository_properties" : {
    "unvadlidated_patterns" : [
        [ "*", "src", "test", "*" ],
        [ "*", "src", "generated", "*" ]
    ]
}
}
```

This is what I get from my method:

`[[u'unvadlidated_patterns'], [u'regeax_flags', u'errdor_message', u'regsex'], [u'validate_branch_name', u'branchd_name_error_message', u'branch_name_regex_flags', u'branch_name_regex'], [u'templadste']]`

And what I want to get is a list of the following entries:

- templadste
- regsex
- regeax_flags
- errdor_message
- branchd_name_error_message
- when_taso_execute
- unvadlidated_patterns

Because these are the ones with actual errors in them.

Comment: Please see my edit I added a lot more information about my specific problem and what I've tried.

Comment: There is no standardised method for getting errors from JSON Schema validation. You will need to look at the documentation for the implementation you are using.

Comment: @Relequestual I have been using this documentation: http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors/#errortrees But I can't seem to manipulate the error tree (as you can see in my code) to get it to give me all of the invalid keys.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python enough to help. If you think the library is not behaving as you expect based on the docs, you should log an issue with the associated issue tracker (probably github somewhere)